# closed ball with topological boundary

Tags: general-topology

For n dimension closed ball $\bar{B}$ as subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ has topological boundary $S^{n-1}$.Since topological boundary is $\bar X - $Int$X$.

For closed ball $\bar B$ as topological space of its own right it has empty topological boundary.

The question is why as topological space of its own right it has empty topological boundary.

Comment: If $\overline{B}$ is the whole universe, then every point of $\overline{B}$ is an interior point.

Comment: Oh thanks,I forget $\bar{B}$ is also open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In any space $X$ the boundary $\partial X$ is empty as $X$ is both open and closed in any space, so the  closure is $X$, and so is the interior.